# Excel CountA not correct when opening workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a .xlsm workbook used as a template (I am using Excel 2010) to create a workbook when users wish to download via a website.

A copy of the template is made when a download is attempted and values are written into a lookup tab in the copy (there are 2 columns: name and id) via .NET code. This part works great.

There is a second tab that uses a COUNTA formula to determine how many rows of data are populated in one of the columns.

My problem is that the COUNTA formula is showing a value of 0 instead of the correct value when the workbook is opened and macros have run. If I were to manually enter the field and refresh the value the value will be correct.

The formula is:

```
=COUNTA(LOOKUP!A2:A1000)
```

Why doesn't this work and what can be done to make it work?

Comment: Is your calculation set to manual?

Comment: I have tried setting to vbAutomatic as well as turning the EnableEvents on or off.

Answer (score -1):

Hello Here is a pretty fast way to count all of the Cells in A

```
Sub btnCount()
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
MsgBox Selection.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: if the above comment is for me then I do not understand what it means

Comment: This does not resolve why when the workbook is opened, the formula is not updated unless a manual action is performed but the result is usable. I used the WorksheetFunction.CountA in VBA code to force a CountA but would rather have a way to force the action to work on the workbook open event.

Comment: This answer is also incorrect as it counts cells with no contents